# How to check which document is deleted on Firestore in Java - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection on Firestore called "Users" and within this collection I have various documents which are phone numbers. Let's say that I have a code on android that can delete numbers with a button. Now how can I see through another code, constantly, which document (number) is being deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect when a document is deleted on another client, you can [attach a realtime listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) to a query for only that document and then [check the changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) until the document gets deleted.

To [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) for a single document, you can set an equality condition on `FieldPath.documentId()`.

So combined that'd be **something like**:

```
db.collection("users")
    .whereEqualTo(FieldPath.documentId(), "idOfDocumentToListenTo")
    .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                            @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "listen:error", e);
                return;
            }

            for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                switch (dc.getType()) {
                    case ADDED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "New user: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                        break;
                    case MODIFIED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "Modified user: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                        break;
                    case REMOVED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "Removed user: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                        //  this is what you're looking for
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Note that this approach can only detect the deletion when it actively happens. If the deletion happened before the call to `addSnapshotListener`, there is no way for a client to know about it anymore and you'd likely have to look at something like [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_deleted) or change the data model to not actually delete the document but instead set a field to mark it as deleted.